# CAS Protocol ticket sent via GET request

Tags: security, get, cas, ticket-system

From [CWE598](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/598.html) sensitive information should be sent using POST request. Why [CAS](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.0.x/protocol/CAS-Protocol.html) protocol sends the ticket value using a GET request as illustrated below? Should it be considered safe in this scenario? From the image:

*"Set the session cookie and forward the browser back to the application with the service ticket stripped off. This optional step prevents the browser address bar from displaying the ST"*

My doubt is: if the browser already sent a GET request including the ticket value in the URL, the ticket could be already logged somewhere or am I wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Why CAS protocol sends the ticket value using a GET request as illustrated below?

There is nothing "sensitive" about the service ticket.

> My doubt is: if the browser already sent a GET request including the ticket value in the URL, the ticket could be already logged somewhere or am I wrong?

This is not part of the protocol and up to the implementations. The Apereo CAS software keeps track of tickets in a "Ticket Registry"